# How can I add a thickness to a curved area?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can draw the following:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(170:1cm)},y={(45:1cm)},z={(90:1cm)}]
\coordinate (O) at (-7,-6,0);
\coordinate (R) at (-3.5,-5,4);
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,-2.5,-1);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (-2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (-2.5,-2.5,-1);
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (2.5,0,0) node[below] {$X_1$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,-3,0) node[below] {$X_2$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,0,2.5) node[right] {$X_3$};

    \filldraw[color=gray!30] 
    (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] (2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mp) (-2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] (-2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mm) (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    -- cycle;
      \draw[very thin] 
    (A)
    to[bend left=25] (B)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mp) (C)
    to[bend right=25] (D)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mm) (A)
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of the above code is

[image]

Please, Any one can help me to modified the picture (Add a 4 layer or more thickness) like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it is rather easy because you have a very nice shape.

**UPDATE**: With colored layers.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(170:1cm)},y={(45:1cm)},z={(90:1cm)}]
\coordinate (O) at (-7,-6,0);
\coordinate (R) at (-3.5,-5,4);
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,-2.5,-1);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (-2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (-2.5,-2.5,-1);
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (2.5,0,0) node[below] {$X_1$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,-3,0) node[below] {$X_2$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,0,2.5) node[right] {$X_3$};

\foreach \Z/\Col [count=\X] in {-1.4/blue,-1.3/red,-1.2/green,-1.1/yellow}
{    \filldraw[color=\Col] 
    (-2.5,2.5,-1) --
    (-2.5,2.5,\Z)
    to[bend right=25] ({-2.5-0.05*(5-\X)},{-2.5-0.05*(5-\X)},\Z)
    to[bend right=25] (2.5,-2.5,\Z)
    -- (2.5,-2.5,-1);
}   
    \filldraw[color=gray!30] 
    (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] (2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mp) (-2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] (-2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mm) (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    -- cycle;


      \draw[very thin] 
    (A)
    to[bend left=25] (B)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mp) (C)
    to[bend right=25] (D)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mm) (A)
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison: with tikz-3dplot. Not necessarily better, but perhaps a bit easier to change the viewing angle and so on.

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{-20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (-7,-6,0);
\coordinate (R) at (-3.5,-5,4);
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,-2.5,-1);
\coordinate (B) at (2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (-2.5,2.5,-1);
\coordinate (D) at (-2.5,-2.5,-1);
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (2.5,0,0) node[below] {$X_1$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,-3,0) node[below] {$X_2$};
    \draw[->] (O) --++ (0,0,2.5) node[right] {$X_3$};

\foreach \Z/\Col [count=\X] in {-1.4/blue,-1.3/red,-1.2/green,-1.1/yellow}
{    \filldraw[color=\Col] 
    (-2.5,2.5,-1) --
    (-2.5,2.5,\Z)
    to[bend left=25] ({-2.5-0.02*(5-\X)},{-2.5-0.02*(5-\X)},\Z)
    to[bend left=25] (2.5,-2.5,\Z)
    -- (2.5,-2.5,-1)  to[bend left=25]  (2.5,2.5,-1)
    -- cycle;
}   
    \filldraw[color=gray!30] 
    (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] (2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mp) (-2.5,2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] (-2.5,-2.5,-1)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mm) (2.5,-2.5,-1)
    -- cycle;


      \draw[very thin] 
    (A)
    to[bend right=25] (B)
    to[bend right=25] coordinate (mp) (C)
    to[bend left=25] (D)
    to[bend left=25] coordinate (mm) (A)
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tank you, It is very nice. But I think there is a little problem hear. In my opinion, the front side of the curved area is very nice but the thickness of the side view is not proper. It seems thick in the start and narrow at the end. Is there a way that can modify the side view?

Comment: @sayros Yes, I can, but it would look more compelling if one uses tikz-3dplot. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Tank you again,  tikz-3dplot is a better option for me. But I dont know how it is possible.

Comment: @sayros I added a tikz-3dplot version. It is not necessarily prettier, but if you want to rotate the view, it might be easier. (But please don't overdo it, I'm pretty sure the back side does not look that good yet ;-)